# NodeJS crypto fails to correctly decrypt the one that was encrypted by some other tools

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I used https://encode-decode.com/aes-256-ctr-encrypt-online/ to encrypt the plain text and then use nodejs crypto aes-2556-ctr algorithm to decrypt but it doesn't return the original text.

plain text: test
Key: 12345678901234567890123456789012

encrypted text using https://encode-decode.com/aes-256-ctr-encrypt-online/: D/EU6g==

Following is the code that I used in nodejs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    key = '12345678901234567890123456789012';

function encrypt(text){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'uft8', 'base64');
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key);
    var dec = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}
```

I can also see that nodejs encrypt returns the different output that the tool I am using to encrypt.

Does anyone know what might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Using createCipheriv worked for me. Thanks!